# Discord bot leaves and will not connect to my server

Tags: node.js, discord.js

While coding my bot, it randomly left along with the other one I was working on. Whenever I try to re-invite it back in the server nothing happens. Sometimes they come back, but both later leave again as soon as I change the channel I am on. Why is this? And yes, ID is replaced with the bot id.

I have tried re-inviting the bot and restarting nodemon.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const server = new Discord.Guild();
//const count = client.channels.get("name","user-count").id;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot logged in as ${client.user.tag}.`);
    //console.log(client.channels.get("name","user-count"));
});



client.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === "update") {
        msg.channel.setName("Member count: 784");
    }
});

//login
client.login('ID');
```

Whenever I re-invite the bot, it tells me that I was authorized. Nodemon does not get any errors.

Comment: how about `client.on('error', console.error);` to catch any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seems that they never left, for some reason it does not show them when I go into channels that they cannot go into.

Comment: This is expected behavior within Discord. Only members able to view the channel will be listed on the side.